# Is there a shortcut key to run a query PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpmyadmin

I run a lot of queries in phpmyadmin because it has a very nice display compared to mysql command line usage. I find it very inconvenient to always have to click the go button instead of pressing a shortcut key to running the query.

Is there a preconfigured shortcut key or a way to define one?

Answer (score 3):

Latest Versions of PHPMyAdmin support  `Ctrl + Enter` and `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: On a Mac, both `Ctrl + Enter` and `⌘ + Enter` work.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Enter` submits on query tab

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Comment: I am using version 4.3.3

Comment: Dang... I'm using  3.4.10.1deb1, I don't think 4.x is available for Ubuntu. I've just done some searches and it seems Ubuntu is 3.5 at the latest (though I haven't found an official page saying so.

Comment: apt-get did automatically installed 4.0.10deb1, but I wanted to have 4.3.3 to equalize other machine. (I installed it straight on a subfolder. apt-get installs on a virtual directory). both versions accepts ctrl-enter. I am using firefox on windows to access it.